# How to create a box-shadow that covers the entire page?

Tags: html, css

the end result that I'm looking for is something like this:

http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/icloud-background.jpg

Which was generated with this bkg title:

http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/apple-shirt.jpg

Is it possible to apply a css3 box-shadow to get the desired output?

I tried:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 490px black;
```

But that only covers a small part of the screen.

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what file-size is that image? That took a while to view; you might consider scaling images down a little, if only for those of us on mobile browsers.

Comment: this is an awesome style, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure whatever element you set the box shadow to has 100% width and height. This means that all ancestors must also have 100% height and width. So if you want to apply it to `body`, `html` must also have those properties.

**CSS:**

```
html, body { 
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
​
body {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 490px black;
    background: url('image.jpg');
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDYTd/2/)

---

To maintain the same shadow effect even when you scroll, apply the box shadow to a `wrapper` div and then apply `overflow:auto`.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, #wrapper { 
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 490px black;
    background: url('image.jpg');
    overflow: auto;
}
```

​
​[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDYTd/3/)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work as when the wrapper is the entire window, the shadow doesn't reach to the center of the window

Comment: @AnApprentice. That won't make a difference in the final product. Look at my updated fiddles with the image included.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly this is what your looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/RGWrC/

Here's the code:

```
html { 
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 490px black;
    background: url('whatever.jpg');
}
```

This extends the background to the full height of the page, still, ensuring a minimum equal to the window's height. The CSS, I think, is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

There is another pretty easy way to do similar effect. 
You have to wrap your website content with div that will have boxshadow. Also the div needs to have 100% width and height, and posiation: absolute; This will give You a nice effect evan when You scroll the page.

HTML

```
<div class="shadow">

    <!-- ANY CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    <div>
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- ANY CONTENT GOES HERE -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 400px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 400px #000000;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2GRGF/1/

Answer (score 2):

I had a task to make a **shadow on the whole page** (for the open CMS EFFCORE) and in the end I found an ingenious and simple solution:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 100000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the image as the page background, then define a container with margins of about 100-200px (depending on how you want the shadow) and fill in this margin with a box-shadow on that div. You could also set the div to a fixed position (I believe) so that it will scroll with the page and maintain the same shadow effect

Edit: setting the image as the page (html or body) background will fix the problem of the image being too small, the div creates the shadow effect that you want

Answer (score 0):

What did you put the shadow on?
You should put the inset shadow on the body, or an element that has 100% size.

The image in the link has the background square repeated and then an inset shadow, probably on the same element that spans across the entire screen

Answer (score 0):

did you set the image tile as a background of your container, and stertch the container across the screen? Then i think the css you suggest should work. Perhaps try a fiddle...