# Bug in Chrome: render big box-shadow

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just want to set box-shadow of div to: `... 0 0 500px ...` (big blur value).

In Google Chrome (last version, windows & ubuntu) I see strange squares-artefacts. In Firefox I get just a normal shadow.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GRGF/1/ (from [How to create a box-shadow that covers the entire page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801790/how-to-create-a-box-shadow-that-covers-the-entire-page))

Is there any workarounds?

[image: Box-shadow bug in chrome]

Comment: For the love of God don't do this. You have paint time between 
`100ms-160ms` in full screen. You don't need to do this.

Comment: @BlagoEreš I need just static light-weight very big glow-effect. Then, what is better way to draw it? SVG?

Comment: I don't know how your design looks like, but I am afraid that currently CSS `box-shadow` is the only option, but performance will degrade and I advise you to not do that. Try to rethink your design and come up with something more pragmatic and performant. `border-radius` + `box-shadow` are still very expensive css properties particularly in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate inset box-shadow using filters. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/igoradamenko/vmeortsf/

HTML:

```
<div class="shadow">
    <div class="blurred"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    background: #555;
}

.blurred {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    border-radius: 50%;

    background: #fff;
    -webkit-filter: blur(100px);
    filter: blur(100px);
}
```

Today filters supported by all modern browsers except IE (all of them). But you may use conditional rules for them. So, it must work at least in IE9+: http://jsfiddle.net/igoradamenko/yywuhx3p/

Comment: In this case, I would prefer radial gradient... Faster.

Comment: @LevChurakov I'm not sure about render/paint speed filters and gradients, but write code for gradients is really faster. To be honest I completely forgot about them. Anyway I'm sure box-shadow slower than each of them.

If you really need box-shadow you should add `transform: translatez(0);` to div with it. It'll speed up shadow and remove some artefacts. Not all, but half a loaf is better than no bread. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your blur-radius is too big.

Although I don't think this is a good idea as @LevChurakov alluded to...

```
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 215px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 215px #000000;
}
```

Comment: I see this bug when border-radius is not so big. Attached image is this jsfiddle screenshot. And in firefox it's smooth & clean.

Comment: -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 215px #000000; You have no FF specific style.

Comment: In FF it works and works good (you don't need any prefixes now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). In Chrome - nope.