# Adding shadow to border in CSS

Tags: css

So far I have this:

```
body {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 10px shadow black;   
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But I would also like to add a shadow.

Comment: This post might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801790/how-to-create-a-box-shadow-that-covers-the-entire-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801790/how-to-create-a-box-shadow-that-covers-the-entire-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a box shadow using the CSS **box-shadow** property, for example:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

There is a handy box shadow generator here which might help you, as you can adjust the properties and get visual feedback:

https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

For shadow:

`box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;`

For border:

`border: 2px solid black;`

If you want to have border and shadow use them both.

Answer (score 0):

Giving shadow to `body` tag is not a good idea, `body` is a canvas to your page and at some stage you will not see the shadow.
Below is a snippet using `div` tag.

```css
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height:200px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);   
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>abc</div>
```